# mouseover bug in IE 9 when using an scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm using `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on an `article` element and it seems that everytime I scroll inside the element both events get fired again in **Internet Explorer 9**.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'article', function () {
    console.log("over!");
});

$(document).on('mouseout', 'article', function () {
    console.log("out!");
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/188/)

The `article` element could be dynamically created. That's why `hover` is not being used.

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <div class="box">Text</div>
    <div class="box">Text</div>
    <div class="box">Text</div>
    <div class="box">Text</div>
    <div class="box">Text</div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article {
    overflow:auto;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried : `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead ?

Comment: @singe31 thanks! It seems to do the trick. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in your events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`